# does nice affect ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a code that uses `ProcessPoolExecutor` to process multiple tables.
Now some of the tables are really light so processing them is quite simple, but for some of the tables the code really struggles and the cpu can be at 99% for a while.
I'm already using sleep whenever I can, and even lowered the amount of workers. But none of it helped. So I wonder if maybe using nice could help me?

Sadly that's all I can share because the code is quite long.

```
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUM_OF_PROCESS_WORKERS) as process_executor:
    process_sstables_per_node(env_tables_dict, nodes, process_executor)


def process_sstables_per_node(env_tables_dict, nodes, process_executor):
    for table_type in TABLES_COLUMNS_MAPPER.keys():
        for node in nodes:
            key = os.path.join(node, table_type)
            env_tables_dict[key] = process_executor.submit(handle_sstable_group_files_per_node, node, table_type)
```

I'm asking because when i call for the the results, I get a log that all of my sub processes stopped working in the middle. Example:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 49, in main
    future.result(timeout=RESULT_TIMEOUT * TIME_CONVERTOR * TIME_CONVERTOR)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 425, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.
My OOM error from the command `dmesg -T | egrep -i 'killed process'`
[image]

Comment: Please show us the full error traceback and tell us on which OS you are.

Comment: I dont really have a traceback but I added how i print the error.
about the nice in this case do i need to use it when i start the main or should it be part of the code

Comment: You are pretty dropping the error traceback with your log line. You should [print out the traceback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3702675/3929826)!

Comment: @KlausD. The error is pretty much the same...

Comment: Probably examine system state - do you get OOM errors or other system log diagnostics?

Comment: @tripleee the problem was OOM so is there a way to fix it?

Comment: More memory. Fewer processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nice` is inherited by subprocesses; so yes. It should be easy to establish experimentally; run `sleep 120` in several processes and examine their nice value in a `ps` listing.

Of course, if your server is running out of juice, there is no way that `nice` will help. Are you running out of memory, or processes, or free file handles, or sockets, or disk space? Then fix those things instead.