# Why is Exception output not captured by contextlib.redirect_stderr context manager?

Tags: python, exception, stdout, stderr

In the following code, I would have expected the exception output and traceback to be written to `test.txt` file, but that does not happen.

```py
import contextlib

with open("test.txt", "a") as f:
    with contextlib.redirect_stderr(f):
        raise Exception("Hello")
```

Why is it not working as expected and how can I correctly redirect the exception output to a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because redirecting `sys.stderr` doesn't catch exceptions in python (it would be bad if it did, right?  Because exceptions are only supposed to be caught by `try/except` blocks.) so the exception handling code interrupts your running code (and the redirect).

Proof:

```py
import contextlib
from sys import stderr

with open("test.txt", "a") as f:
    with contextlib.redirect_stderr(f):
        sys.stderr.write("hello")
        sys.stderr.flush()
```

writes correctly.

To redirect the output from all exceptions to a file you have two options:  catch all exceptions globally in a `try/except` block and do the writing yourself, or use shell redirection to send the *script's* stderr to a file, with something like

```sh
python my_script.py 2>errors.txt
```

If you want to do it yourself, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702675/how-to-catch-and-print-the-full-exception-traceback-without-halting-exiting-the) for discussion of getting the traceback.

Comment: Thanks. I think I can wrap my head around it: it's because the runtime, including the contextlib's stderr redirection is interrupted and stops when the exception arises, the output being then propagated outside the redirection. I went for a try/except block solution (as you suggest) inside a custom context manager

Comment: @JeanMonet exactly  :)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an alternative implementation I went for.

The following is redirecting the exception output to a logger. In my case the logger was set to stdout (default) so I used `contextlib.redirect_stdout` to redirect the logger's output to a file, but you could of course directly make the logger write to a file.

```py
import logging
import contextlib
from typing import Iterator


@contextlib.contextmanager
def capture_exception(logger: logging.Logger) -> Iterator[None]:
    """
    Captures exceptions and redirects output to the logger
    >>> import logging
    >>> logger = logging.getLogger()
    >>> with capture_exception(logger=logger):
    >>>     raise Exception("This should be outputed to the logger")
    """
    try:
        # try/except block where exception is captured and logged
        try:
            yield None
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(e)
    finally:
        pass
```

Usage:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger()   # default should be stdout

with open("test.txt", "a") as f:
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f), capture_exception(logger):
        # ^-- multiple context managers in one `with` statement
        raise Exception("The output of this exception will appear in the log. Great success.")
```

Exception output as it appears in the log:

```
The output of this exception will appear in the log. Great success.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_9802/2529855525.py", line 52, in capture_exception
    yield None
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_9802/3344146337.py", line 9, in <module>
    raise Exception("The output of this exception will appear in the log. Great success.")
Exception: The output of this exception will appear in the log. Great success.
```