# Youtube video Downloader Error invalid video

Tags: python, download, youtube, pytube

PYTUBE Error downloading video

i wanted to download a youtube video using pytube but all it did was say that the video was invalid
i need help analyzing the issue

this it the code i used

```
import customtkinter
import tkinter
from pytube import YouTube


def startdownload():
    try:
        ytLink = Link.get()
        ytObject = YouTube(ytLink)
        video = ytObject.streams.get_highest_resolution()  # change this line
        video.download()
    except:
        print("YouTube link is invalid")
    print("youtube Link complete")




# Adding UI Elements
title = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="Insert a youtube link")
title.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

# Link Input
url_var = tkinter.StringVar()
Link = customtkinter.CTkEntry(app, width=350, height=40, textvariable=url_var)
Link.pack()

# Download Button
download = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, text="Download", command=startdownload)
download.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
```

Comment: What is the `ytLink` you provided?

Comment: Also add the value of `Link`. Also [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3702847/4092887) about how you can get extra details of the exception.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: firstly the ytLink is user input i tried multiple links though

Comment: are you suggesting this except as Link: