# turtle colormode(255) color((r,g,b)) set with integers but color() returns floats and color(with floats) complains

Tags: python, python-turtle

The concern is why doesn't color() accept any result color() returns?  In this case, I would suggest, with a quick look at the turtle code, a simple solution would be to convert the color tuple to ints before attempting to convert the tuple to the hex value.
**example:**

```
#color_mode_issue.py    11Jul2023, crs
"""
turtle colormode(255) color((r,g,b)) set with integers
but color() returns floats
and color(with floats) complains
"""
from turtle import *
colormode(255)
rgb = (0,134,255)       # cerulean, one shade
print("Setting color using color(", rgb, ")")
color(rgb)              # Set color
fg = color()[0]         # Get forground
print(fg, "is returned by color()")
print("Using color(", fg, ") has problems")
try:
    color(fg)               # Use color() returned value
except Exception as ex:
    print("oops...", ex)
    fg_int = tuple([int(x) for x in fg])# tuple to ints
    print("...but color(", fg_int, ") works OK")
    color(fg_int)
```

**Output:**

```
Setting color using color( (0, 134, 255) )
(0.0, 134.0, 255.0) is returned by color()
Using color( (0.0, 134.0, 255.0) ) has problems
oops... %x format: an integer is required, not float
...but color( (0, 134, 255) ) works OK
```

Comment: How does knowing why help you?

Comment: If the response had mentioned the value(s) were out-of-range I would have scaled my values or changed the colormode instead of looking in a different direction such as using multiple args instead of a tuple...

Comment: But nothing *is* "out-of-range".  And you're still left with the problem of making a `color` out of what `color()` returns.

Comment: I suspect the reason it returns floats is to support the output after a call of `colormode(1.0)`.  That doesn't totally explain why it couldn't return ints though.  It seems best option is to use color strings such as "limegreen" or magenta", and then `color()` will return the strings.

Comment: My guess, in the case of converting r,g,b to 0xRRGGBB, the problem could be avoided by converting floats to ints on the color((r,g,b) input side.

Comment: Remember that `turtle` is a toy designed for teaching.  Once you get beyond toy applications, you need to move to a real UI.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [CPython GH issue #71406 from 2016](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/71406).

For starters, instead of printing "X has problems", you'll get more information by [dumping the whole stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3702847/6243352):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/a.py", line 15, in <module>
    color(fg)               # Use color() returned value
  File "<string>", line 8, in color
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/turtle.py", line 2216, in color
    pcolor = self._colorstr(pcolor)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/turtle.py", line 2696, in _colorstr
    return self.screen._colorstr(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/turtle.py", line 1167, in _colorstr
    return "#%02x%02x%02x" % (r, g, b)
TypeError: %x format: an integer is required, not float
```

You ask:

> why doesn't `color()` accept any result `color()` returns?

The general answer is that Python's turtle module is rather poorly-designed and hacky in many respects, both in its internal implementation as well as the public API. Many methods are overloaded, with different modes, acting as both getters and setters depending on whether they're called with arguments or not. This breaks the single-responsibility principle. Adding widespread aliasing into the mix makes things even more confusing, breaking the Zen of Python: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.".

Specifically, the `color` method is a classic source of frustration, since it's multi-modal and accepts different types, ints, strings and floats. As such, the return value is multi-modal as well (not to mention multi-purpose, returning both outline and fill colors). Given the complexity of the method contract, the developers probably overlooked your particular use case, leading to surprising behavior (or an outright bug, if you prefer).

Internally, colors are [converted to and stored as a hexadecimal color string](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c829975428253568d47ebfc3104fa7386b5e0b58/Lib/turtle.py#L1133) when you call `color()` with a tuple. Your original argument is discarded in the conversion. When getting the value later, the color string is [re-parsed to a tuple if it doesn't start with `#`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c829975428253568d47ebfc3104fa7386b5e0b58/Lib/turtle.py#L1160) (comments are mine):

```py
def _color(self, cstr):
    # this branch is not taken in our case; used for "black", "red", etc
    if not cstr.startswith("#"):
        return cstr
    if len(cstr) == 7:
        cl = [int(cstr[i:i+2], 16) for i in (1, 3, 5)]
    elif len(cstr) == 4:
        cl = [16*int(cstr[h], 16) for h in cstr[1:]]
    else:
        raise TurtleGraphicsError("bad colorstring: %s" % cstr)

    # recreate a tuple from the color string, using floats
    return tuple(c * self._colormode/255 for c in cl)
```

A better general design might be to use separate methods for getting/setting color in each mode, or use kwargs to clarify which type of setting/getting is being performed. Furthermore, separating the internal color representation and the argument provided by the user may avoid the unusual behavior here.

The most direct solution would be ensuring that floats are returned when the color mode is 1.0 and ints otherwise, something like:

```py
# Potentially buggy(?) float comparison, but used elsewhere in the code.
# math.isclose() is the correct float comparison, but perhaps the
# literal 1.0 can be trusted due to an implementation detail, like
# `1.0 is 1.0` evaluates to True. The design is weird but beside the point.
if self._colormode == 1.0:
    return tuple(c * self._colormode/255 for c in cl)

return tuple(cl)
```

Another solution Python could use is to convert floats to integers when building the color string in `_colorstr()`, e.g. `"#%02x%02x%02x" % (int(r), int(g), int(b))`, but I'm not too crazy about this since it silently truncates information. Even if done conditionally to ensure all floats are whole numbers, the contract still feels weird.

As a workaround, if you use color mode 1.0 or strings, the get/set operations should be consistent. Or write a wrapper on the `color` method to convert the argument to ints. Or avoid keeping color state in the turtle and instead only use `color()` in setter mode, using your own value as a getter.

As an aside, avoid `from turtle import *` which dumps over a hundred methods into the global namespace, and tends to lead to confusion when programmers mix up the instance and functional interfaces.

Comment: It may be true that turtle's design might be improved, and because turtle continues to be used A LOT,  it might serve the user community to improve it when possible.  As pointed out turtle usage is in education so we should consider making it kindler / gentler to the learning audience.

Comment: Of course I'm all for improving turtle, but I'm also not involved in its development and it's possible that for backwards compatibility reasons, many parts of the API can't be changed. Mainly, I try to note the gotchas I've seen so it's easier to avoid them when working with it.