# how to get more info from try/except

Tags: python, paramiko, try-except

I'm having problems with my code in python where basically I make several SSH connection.
I'm always using this format:

```
try:
 ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
 ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())
 ssh.connect(IP, username=USER_GW, password=PSW_GW,look_for_keys=False) 
 stdin, stdout, stderr=ssh.exec_command(command, timeout=60)
 output=stdout.read().decode('ascii').strip("\n")         
except Exception e:
 print (e)
finally:
    ssh.close()
    stdin.close()
    stdout.close()
    stderr.close()
```

the error I'm getting is

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last)
os.replace(local_folder+'/file1', local_folder+"/file2")
```

but this exception is driving me in a wrong direction since file1 is not downloaded from the previous try/except/finally.

So I'm wondering if exist another way to show more information related to the paramiko error (instead of `except Exception e`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catch and print full Python exception traceback without halting/exiting the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702675/catch-and-print-full-python-exception-traceback-without-halting-exiting-the-prog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, can display the traceback of code executed

```
import traceback

...
except Exception e:
    print (e)
    print(traceback.format_exc())
...
```