# How to obtain an exception with a `__traceback__` attribute that contains the stack outside a `try`

Tags: python, python-3.x

It seems that in Python (3.10) an exception that is raised inside a `try` contains a traceback that does not extend to the calling location of the `try`.
This is somewhat surprising to me, and more importantly, not what I want.

Here's a short program that illustrates the problem:

```
# short_tb.py
import traceback


def caller():
    somefunction()


def somefunction():
    try:
        raise ValueError("This is a value error")
    except ValueError as e:
        # in my actual code, e is passed to a function, and __traceback__ is pulled from it for logging at this other
        # location; the code below simply demonstrates the lack of frames in the traceback object
        print("".join(traceback.format_tb(e.__traceback__)))


print("This will produce a traceback with only one frame, the one in somefunction()")
caller()


def caller2():
    somefunction2()


def somefunction2():
    raise ValueError("This is a value error")


print("This will produce a traceback with all relevant frames (the default behavior of the python interpreter)")
caller2()
```

output:

```
This will produce a traceback with only one frame, the one in somefunction()
  File ".../short_tb.py", line 10, in somefunction
    raise ValueError("This is a value error")

This will produce a traceback with all relevant frames (the default behavior of the python interpreter)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../short_tb.py", line 30, in <module>
    caller2()
  File ".../short_tb.py", line 22, in caller2
    somefunction2()
  File ".../short_tb.py", line 26, in somefunction2
    raise ValueError("This is a value error")
ValueError: This is a value error
```

what I want is for `__traceback__` to contain all the information in the second example. I'm happy to overwrite the variable and I can do so at the exception-handling location... but how do I get an object to use for that purpose?

in this question there are many answers about tracebacks, but none of them seem to be about `traceback objects`:
[Catch and print full Python exception traceback without halting/exiting the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702675/catch-and-print-full-python-exception-traceback-without-halting-exiting-the-prog)

Comment: The traceback is a record of what frames the exception passed through between being raised and being caught, not the state of the stack when the exception was raised.

Comment: If you want a snapshot of the stack, I think you need to grab that with the `inspect` module when the exception is first created.

Comment: @chepner this may be the explanation of why the information is lacking, but that in itself doesn't really help me (and the developers of Python seem to agree there's a need for another behavior, as evidenced by the Python interpreter's default behavior)

Comment: @chepner do you happen to know which of the `inspect` module's functions would yield a result of the correct type?

Comment: I think [`inspect.stack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.stack) is what you want.

Comment: Trying to assign inspect.stack gives a `"TypeError: __traceback__ must be a traceback or None"` ... which brings us back to the question "how do I get a traceback object" for assigning into the exception?

Comment: What do you mean, "assign"? Are you trying to copy the stack *into* the traceback? That's not what the traceback is for. Just attach the current stack to the exception directly, so that when the exception *is* caught, you can examine that stack.

Comment: I am trying to `e.__traceback__ = inspect.stack()`, such that when code (that is out of my control) that inspects `__traceback__` can take it from there. What do you mean by "attach to the exception directly"?

Comment: Yes, *don't do that*. The traceback is not a stack; it's a list of stack frames, sure, but it's not the stack itself. If you want the stack, attached it directly to `e`: `e.stack_when_raised = inspect.stack()`.

Comment: But if you can't do that when `e` is created, it's too late. The stack you want *does not exist* by the time you catch the exception. That's why the traceback is there: when you catch the exception, between `inspect.stack()` and `e.__traceback__` you can *reconstruct* what the stack would have looked like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more correct handling is already suggested by @Mark Tolonen, but if it's really necessary for `__traceback__` to contain a full stack:

- Use `tb_frame.f_back` to access the previous frames.
- Reconstruct traceback objects using `types.TracebackType`.
- Link them with `tb_next` constructor argument.

```py
import traceback
import types


def caller(full = False):
    somefunction(full)

def somefunction(full):
    try:
        raise ValueError("This is a value error")
    except ValueError as e:
        if full:
            complete_traceback(e)
        print("".join(traceback.format_tb(e.__traceback__)))

def complete_traceback(exception):
    t = exception.__traceback__
    fb = t.tb_frame.f_back
    while fb:
        t = types.TracebackType(tb_next=t,
                                tb_frame=fb,
                                tb_lasti=fb.f_lasti,
                                tb_lineno=fb.f_lineno)
        fb = t.tb_frame.f_back
    exception.__traceback__ = t


print("This will produce a traceback with only one frame, the one in somefunction()")
caller()

print("This will produce a traceback with all relevant frames")
caller(True)
```

Output:

```
This will produce a traceback with only one frame, the one in somefunction()
  File ".../short_tb.py", line 10, in somefunction
    raise ValueError("This is a value error")

This will produce a traceback with all relevant frames
  File ".../short_tb.py", line 32, in <module>
    caller(True)
  File ".../short_tb.py", line 6, in caller
    somefunction(full)
  File ".../short_tb.py", line 10, in somefunction
    raise ValueError("This is a value error")
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @chepner in the comments, "the traceback is a record of what frames the exception passed through between being raised and being caught, not the state of the stack when the exception was raised.", but the `traceback` module can also generate the stack frame at the current point in the code, so the following prints the entire stack frame in a helper function:

```py
import traceback
import sys

def print_full_exception_stack():
    etype, e, tb = sys.exc_info()
    s = traceback.extract_stack()[:2]  # Frames up to where this helper function was called.
    t = traceback.extract_tb(tb)       # Frames to the exception.
    L = traceback.format_list(s + t)   # Join and format the frames.
    print('Traceback (most recent call last):')
    print(''.join(L).rstrip())
    print(f'{etype.__name__}: {e}')

def caller():
    somefunction()

def somefunction():
    try:
        raise ValueError('This is a value error')
    except ValueError:
        print_full_exception_stack()

caller()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\test.py", line 17, in <module>
    caller()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\test.py", line 4, in caller
    somefunction()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\test.py", line 8, in somefunction
    raise ValueError('This is a value error')
ValueError: This is a value error
```