# How to negate a value with if/else logic in python?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner with using Python. I have two values that I want to setup if/else logic with. One is the **"obj.default_value"** and the other is the **"obj.override"**.

The basic summary to my problem is I want to setup an if/else statement that checks if **obj.override** == 'true' then **obj.default_value** should change to 'True'. If **obj.override** == 'false' then **obj.default_value** should change to 'False'. The final option is if **obj.override** == 'none' then **obj.default_value** should stay to the current value it was.

Better yet, if possible I would like the **obj.override** to negate the value of **obj.default_value**. True becomes false and vice versa. I want to setup a new function that overrides the default value. I hope I explained all this well and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my current code for two values referenced:

```
    def default_value_custom(self, obj):
        color = 'green' if obj.default_value else 'red'
        return mark_safe("<span style='color:%s'>%s</span>" % (color, obj.default_value))
    default_value_custom.short_description = 'default value'


    def override_custom(self, obj):
        if obj.override == 'true':
            return mark_safe("Always <span style='color:green'>True</span>")
        elif obj.override == 'false':
            return mark_safe("Always <span style='color:red'>False</span>")
        else:
            return obj.override
```

Here's a screenshot as well of the admin view.
[image]

Comment: It is `True` and `False` in Python; uppercase not lowercase

Comment: @dawg This is true, but the provided code seems to be checking string values, not booleans directly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python how should I test if a variable is None, True or False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020598/in-python-how-should-i-test-if-a-variable-is-none-true-or-false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's summarize:

1. The condition `if value:` (and also `while value:`) tests, whether the `value` evaluates to boolean true. Many call such values "truthy" or "truish".

   The negated condition `if not value:` tests the opposite, i.e. whether the `value` evaluates to boolean false. Such values are called "falsy".

   *Truthy* is everything not *falsy*; typical *falsy* values are:

   - constants defined to be false: None and False.
   - zero of any numeric type: 0, 0.0, 0j, Decimal(0), Fraction(0, 1)
   - empty sequences and collections: '', (), [], {}, set(), range(0)

   (quoted from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), click for more details)
2. Any value can be converted to boolean `True` or `False` with `bool(value)`. In other words: *truthy* just means that `bool(value)` evalues to `True`.
3. The remaining question is how to test for a constant `True` ( or `False` or `None`) and not just any truthy (or falsy) value. The answer is:

   ```
    if value is True: # or False/None
        ...
   ```

---

The function you were asking for is:

```
def overriden(value, override):
    return value if override is None else override
```